# git send-pack: protocol error: bad band #50

Tags: git, git-remote

I am trying to push some files to a server with git push. I have configured the server to push the files:

```
git remote set-url test ssh://user@location.com:2200/fullpath/
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
git send-pack: protocol error: bad band #50
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

It seems that something is failing on the remote side but I can't find any reference to this protocol error.

Does anyone know how to solve this error? Or which logs should I search to better understand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Start with providing *full* information on your setup: versions of software running on both sides as well as flavors/versions of OSes on both sides. This is needed because there's more than one Git implementation (both client- and server-side) so at least anyone who's about to guess the reason for your problem should start there.

Also this problem seems (to me) hardcore enough to warrant posting to the main Git list (for developers) — see [this](https://gist.github.com/tfnico/4441562) for more info.

As a side note, provided you have the standard vanilla Git on both sides, I would suspect that something other (not Git) is talking with you on the server side, so instead of the Git protocol your Git client sees that gibberish, tries to interpret it, and fails.
So could you at least try to just do

```
 ssh -p 2200 user@location.com 'git --version'
```

and see if you get back something sensible?

Comment: That command returned 'git version 1.7.9.5'. The same as my local machine.

My local machine is running Ubuntu 12.10 and the remote is running ubuntu 12.04 (a vps hosting)